# make: how to use a file as target and skip the target if that file already exists?

Tags: makefile

My `Makefile` looks like this (with some irrelevant targets such as 'debug' removed):

```
release: comprel
a2s: release
libtelopa.so:
    cd telop/neta/lib && make && cp libtelopa.so ../../../
comprel: libtelopa.so
    go build -ldflags="-s -w" .
    upx --best --lzma a2ssvr
clean:
    cd telop/neta/lib && make clean
    git clean -fdX
distclean: clean
    rm -fr a2s_*.deb
deb: a2s libtelopa.so
    rm -fr debian.deb
    cp libtelopa.so debian/opt/a2s/bin
    cp libjson/* debian/opt/a2s/bin
    cp a2ssvr debian/opt/a2s/bin/a2s
    dpkg-deb --build --root-owner-group debian
    rm -fr a2s*.deb
    dpkg-name debian.deb
```

If I check-out a fresh copy from git repository, it works fine.  However, after I make the project an executable `a2ssvr` is generated in the project root folder, in such case, if I run `make deb` again, I hope the `release` target is **not** called. However, it is called every time I do `make deb`.  Strangely, the `libtelopa.so` target is **NOT** called if the file is already there.

What is the problem, how can I avoid build the executable if it is already built?

**EDIT**

Based on the answers and comments, I would like to explain why the Make rules are wrote as such, let me first give out a modified Makefile:

```
BRANCH=$(shell git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
HASH=$(shell git log -n1 --pretty=format:%h)
REVS=$(shell git log --oneline|wc -l)

.PHONY: release comprel setver
debug: compdbg
release: comprel
a2ssvr: release
libtelopa.so:
    cd telop/neta/lib && make && cp libtelopa.so ../../../
comprel: libtelopa.so
    go build -ldflags="-s -w" . && mv a2ssvr a2s
    upx --best --lzma a2ssvr
compdbg: libtelopa.so
    go build -race -gcflags=all=-d=checkptr=0 . && mv a2ssvr a2s
deb: a2ssvr libtelopa.so
    rm -fr debian.deb
    cp libtelopa.so debian/opt/a2s/bin
    cp libjson/* debian/opt/a2s/bin
    cp a2ssvr debian/opt/a2s/bin/a2s
    dpkg-deb --build --root-owner-group debian
    rm -fr a2s*.deb
    dpkg-name debian.deb
```

The rationale and workflow are:

1. default target **debug** is used during daily development.
2. the reason to define **comprel** and **compdbg**, rather than write the code directly under **debug** and **release** is that they share a common rule **setver** which write GIT revision info directly into the source code.
3. comprel/compdbg relies on `libtelopa.so`, because the program uses CGO.
4. I want the **deb** target to **NOT** check freshness of its dependencies, given the file **a2s** and **libtelopa.so** exists they should **NOT** be rebuilt.

According to the answers/comments, I added **.PHONY** targets, but it **does not** work.  As a matter of fact, I already tried that before intially asking the question.

I changed the `a2s` target as follow:

```
a2s: libtelopa.so
    cp verinfo.tpl version.go
    sed -i 's/{_BRANCH}/$(BRANCH)/' version.go
    sed -i 's/{_G_HASH}/$(HASH)/' version.go
    sed -i 's/{_G_REVS}/$(REVS)/' version.go
    go build -ldflags="-s -w" . && mv a2ssvr a2s
    upx --best --lzma a2s
```

This will "partially" work, as the "a2s" target will make **twice**, I then change the rule to "order only":

```
a2s: |libtelopa.so
```

which worked as expected. However, I do **NOT** want to rewrite all build scripts in different targets!

My intention is clear: if the "a2s" file does not exist, `make` should use the named rule to build it, if it does exist, that file should be used directly.  To accomplish this, I now make the `release` target "phony" which I think should tell `make` that this target is not a real file.

Comment: Mark non-file targets .PHONY.  Target is only rebuild if it's older than its dependencies.

Comment: `deb` depends on `a2ssvr` and `a2ssvr` depends on `release`. If the dependencies are not correct, what should they be instead?

Comment: The question in the title seems to be about the diametrically opposite problem (which is also the default behavior of `make` out of the box anyway) so this is rather confusing.

Comment: @tripleee, if a2ssvr already exist, what it depends should not matter, right?? if I do not add `a2ssvr: release`, the make will fail if a2ssvr does not exist, which is the initial case anyway.

Comment: If it depends on a file which does not "yet" exist, it will be remade. If `comprel` is also not a real file, probably change the dependencies so that `comprel` depends on `a2ssvr`, and the latter is attached to the actual recipe. Ultimately, any targets which do not correspond to an actual file should be `.PHONY:` as already pointed out in comments and the answer you already received. If you still need more help, perhaps [edit] your question to explain in more details what files exist and how the depencency chains correspond to actual reality.

Comment: This all seems to resolve to the age-old "I put in bogus depencencies because I am confused, and now `make` is too."

Answer (score 1):

It's not overly clear what you're after, but if I understand correctly, then you want to only build the `release` target iff `a2ssvr` is out of date?   (where release causes comprel to run, which in turn creates an artifact called a2ssvr...)

If that's the case, all you have to do is to collapse the phony targets that trigger `a2ssvr` into a target named `a2ssvr`... (note that it's good practice to have a target name match the artifact its recipes generate).   So now you would have:

```
a2ssvr: libtelopa.so
    go build -ldflags="-s -w" .
    upx --best --lzma a2ssvr

libtelopa.so: telop/neta/lib/libtelopa.so
    cp $< $@

clean:
    cd telop/neta/lib && make clean
    git clean -fdX

distclean: clean
    rm -fr a2s_*.deb

deb: a2ssvr
    rm -fr debian.deb
    cp libtelopa.so debian/opt/a2s/bin
    cp libjson/* debian/opt/a2s/bin
    cp a2ssvr debian/opt/a2s/bin/a2s
    dpkg-deb --build --root-owner-group debian
    rm -fr a2s*.deb
    dpkg-name debian.deb

.PHONY: deb clean distclean

# for order only, you would need:
# deb: libtelopa.so | a2ssvr
```

Now, your wording implies that you don't want to rebuild `a2ssrv` if it *exists* (as opposed to when it's out of date).   If that's the case you can switch the `a2ssvr` dependency to be [order only](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html).  This would mean, however, that it would not be rebuilt if it existed, but  `libtelopa.so` had been modified (which I am guessing is not what you want...)

Comment: yes my intention is that the target should only be built if a2ssvr does not **exist**, I don't really care if it is outdated or not. Because for this project, it is pretty hard to determine if the target is outdated or not, e.g. the source code refers to a git submodule...   However, for this question, my intention is to learn **WHY** the libtelopa.so target works as expected (i.e. will not tirgger if the .so file already exist), yet the a2ssver target will trigger even if the file already exists!

Comment: I don't understand why the wording "exist" or "out-dated" will confuse you.  The problem is obvious, I run `make` for the first time, a2ssvr target is run and the file is generated. Then I run `make` again, **immediately**, the target is **still** run, regardless of the file exists already -- I don't believe that the newly generated a2ssvr file can be outdated!

Comment: Yes, but what is the desired behavior if you then modify `libtelopa.so`, and run make again -- should it rerun the `a2ssvr` recipes?  (I'm guessing it should).   With order-only, it will not rebuild it as long as the file exists.   If that's the desired behavior then you can replace the `deb` dependencies with the ones from the comment.

Comment: As to your first comment: the rule for `libtelopa.so` refers to a filename.  Because it has no dependencies, it will be built if and only if the file `libtelopa.so` doesn't already exist (note: technically it should depend on `telop/neta/lib/libtelopa.so`, so if that is updated it rebuilds...).   As for your `comprel` target, it will be rebuilt if the file `comprel` did not exist or any of its dependencies are out of date.  Because you don't generate a file called `comprel`, that target is always considered out of date, and rerun.

Answer (score 1):

> how to use a file as target and skip the target if that file already exists?

If the only criterion you want to consider for whether to run the recipe for a given target is whether the target name designates an existing file, then that corresponds to excluding (ordinary) prerequisites.  With GNU `make`, you should also be careful to *not* declare the target `.PHONY`:

```
a2ssvr: 
    go build -ldflags="-s -w" .
    upx --best --lzma $@
```

GNU `make` provides non-standard "order-only" prerequisites as an extension.  If you are willing to rely specifically on this `make` implementation (which is widely used but not universal) then you can use these to influence the order in which the recipe is run relative to other targets' recipes.  Inasmuch as your original makefile suggests that the `a2ssvr` build depends on `libtelopa.so`, you are asking for trouble if you do not make the latter *at least* an order-only prerequisite:

```
a2ssvr: | libtelopa.so
    go build -ldflags="-s -w" .
    upx --best --lzma $@
```

But this sets up a situation where `a2ssvr` will not be rebuilt if it exists but is out of date with respect to `libtelopa.so`.  It sounds like you are assuming that the makefile will be used only for clean builds, so that this situation will not arise, but that's short-sighted.  Especially so when it is cleaner, clearer, and more portable to simply specify an ordinary dependency:

```
a2ssvr: libtelopa.so
    go build -ldflags="-s -w" .
    upx --best --lzma $@
```

---

So, let's consider your description of the observed behavior:

> If I check-out a fresh copy from git repository, it works fine.

Yes.  This is presumably a clean build.

> However, after I make the project an executable `a2ssvr` is generated in the project root folder,

Yes.

> in such case, if I run `make deb` again, I hope the `release` target is **not** called.

Wait now.  This is a different issue than is expressed in the question's headline.

> However, it is called every time I do `make deb`.

Yes. The `release` target is built because it is a prerequisite of `a2ssvr`, which is a prerequisite of `deb`, which is the target you asked for, and because no file named `release` exists.

> Strangely, the `libtelopa.so` target is **NOT** called if the file is already there.

That's not strange at all, given the makefile.  `libtelopa.so` is not rebuilt because it already exists, and it is not out of date relative to any of its prerequisites (because it doesn't have any prerequisites).  This target is built using recursive `make`, which means the top-level `make` doesn't have a full dependency tree to rely on.  And the recursion is set up *poorly*, with the result that if `libtelopa.so` exists then it will not be rebuilt even when it ought to be.  That's not an issue for a clean build, but again, assuming clean builds is short-sighted.

---

Some general principles:

- Each file to be built should be built **directly** by a rule whose target matches the file's name.
- Rules should express (all the) true dependencies of their targets.
- Rules *should not* specify prerequisites on which their targets do not actually depend.  Rules for building files usually should not depend on phony targets, whether those are explicitly maked `.PHONY` or not.
- Minimize the use of phony targets overall, especially those that do not have established conventional meanings.